# Swift 3 - How to set up Local Notification at specific date

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar, uilocalnotification

I need your help for a project. 
I have 3 variables, one for the day , another for the month and last for the year. Like that :

`var year = 2017
var month = 06
var day = 19`

I want to send a notification even if the app is close when we are at the date of these variable, but i'm not really good with Calendar and Date. I just made this app for the moment.

```
let myNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue:"MyNotification")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(forName:myNotification, object:nil, queue:nil, using:catchNotification)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.post(name:myNotification,
            object: nil,
            userInfo:["message":"Hello there!", "date":Date()])
}

func catchNotification(notification:Notification) -> Void {
    print("Catch notification")

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let message  = userInfo["message"] as? String,
        let date     = userInfo["date"]    as? Date else {
            print("No userInfo found in notification")
            return
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification!",
                                  message:"\(message) received at \(date)",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set up a local notification and use a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` to fire it at a specific date.

```
let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day)
let yourFireDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey:
            "Your notification title", arguments: nil)
content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Your notification body", arguments: nil)
content.categoryIdentifier = "Your notification category"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
content.badge = 1

let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set(arrayLiteral: Calendar.Component.year, Calendar.Component.month, Calendar.Component.day), from: yourFireDate)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Your notification identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
        if let error = error {
            //handle error
        } else {
            //notification set up successfully
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of "yourFireDate" ?

Comment: it is a `Date` object you initialize using your variables year, month and day.

Comment: so i set `let yourFireDate = year + month + day`

Comment: No, how could you initialize a `Date` object by simply adding 3 integers? You have to use `DateComponents`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Nothing happends :/ i think its cause of date i will set the date to tomorrow

Comment: Did you request authorisation for the notifications?

Comment: I have add a hour and a minute and ITS WORKS thank you ^^

Comment: Oh yeah, without those the date defaults to 12AM. Glad I could help.

Comment: Call `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests`, which will return all notifications that you have created but haven't been delivered yet.

Comment: Xcode say missing argument, 
it want `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: <#([UNNotificationRequest]) -> Void#>)`. But i don't know what enter insinde the completionHandler

Comment: This will print you the requests, if you want to do anything else with them you can iterate through the array `pendingRequests` and handle each request one by one.
`center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { pendingRequests in
            print("Pending notifications: \(pendingRequests)")
        })`

Comment: This was what i would like ^^ : `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { (notificationRequests) in
            var identifiers: [String] = []
            for notification:UNNotificationRequest in notificationRequests {
                if notification.identifier == "FirstNotif" {
                    print("Already Exist")
                }
            }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

In **swift 3 - 4** use this.

```
  func scheduleLocal() {

        let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: 2019, month: 1, day: 17, hour: 10, minute: 20)
        let yourFireDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.fireDate = yourFireDate
        notification.alertBody = "Hey you! Yeah you! Swipe to unlock!"
        notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)


    }
```